# I need help figuring out why is this not working. (C)

Tags: c

[This is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GabDw.png) This code needs to print out 2 maximum numbers, when -999 is entered the code needs to stop.
 I tried every thing but most of the times i get the maximum number but not the second maximum number.

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main ()
{
    int x = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int max2 = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int flag = 0; 
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the number  -999 to stop: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x != -999)
        {
            if (x > max)
            {
                max = x;  
                max2 = y;   
            }
            printf("Enter the number  -999 to stop: ");                      
            scanf("%d", &y);
            if (y != -999)
            {
                if (y > max)
                {   
                    max = y;
                    max2 = x;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
    while (flag == 0);
    printf("The max number is: %d\n", max);
    printf("The second max number is: %d\n", max2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding some sample input and output might help.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. 1 10 10

Comment: You only need to read and check once per loop.

Comment: The 3rd number you enter will be compared only once, even though you should compare it to the 2nd max as well

Comment: "This is what I get" > an image. But your code does not produce an image.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main ()
{
    int x = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int max2 = 0;
    int flag = 0; 

 do
 {
     printf("Enter the number  -999 to stop: ");
     scanf("%d", &x);
     if (x != -999)
     {   // bigger than max?
         if (x > max)
         {   
             // since the new max is x and the old max is bigger than max2
             max2 = max;
             max = x;     
         }
         // bigger than max2?
         else if (x > max2)
         {   
            max2 = x;
         }

     }
     else // exit loop
     {
         flag = 1;
     }
    }
 while (flag == 0);
 printf("The max number is: %d\n", max);
 printf("The second max number is: %d\n", max2);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in your code, there is no `y`, therefore you can not use `max2 = y`, and that is one of the problem of the original code.

Answer (score 0):

There are more problems in your code.

You have unnecessary two inputs (x and y), then you wrongly assume, when `x > max`, then y contains second max, and when `y > max` then x contains second max.

Correct code should look like this:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int max2 = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        printf("Enter the number (-999 to stop): ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x == -999)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (x > max)
        {
            max2 = max;
            max = x;
        }
        else if (x > max2)
        {
            max2 = x;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nThe max number is: %d\n", max);
    printf("The second max number is: %d\n", max2);

    return 0;
}
```